# SCIP: PySCIPOpt error when importing Model

Tags: python, model, scip

`dfg@dfg:~/prog/scipoptsuite-4.0.1/build$ cmake .. -DREADLINE=off
-- Build type: Release
-- Build shared libraries: ON
-- Build type: Release
-- LEGACY mode for old compilers: OFF
-- Could NOT find IPOPT (missing: IPOPT_LIBRARIES) 
-- Could NOT find CRITERION (missing: CRITERION_LIBRARY CRITERION_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- The following OPTIONAL packages have been found:

- ZLIB
- GMP

-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

- BISON
- FLEX
- SOPLEX
- SCIP

-- The following OPTIONAL packages have not been found:

- IPOPT
- Criterion

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dfg/prog/scipoptsuite-4.0.1/build`

[error : libscip.so not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Ezl.png)I am trying to run the 'atsp.py' example provided in github but I encountered an error:

```
/home/dfg/thesis/programming/python_envs/scip_env/bin/python3.6 atsp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "atsp.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pyscipopt import Model, quicksum, multidict
  File "/home/dfg/thesis/programming/python_envs/scip_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyscipopt/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyscipopt.scip      import Model
ImportError: /opt/scipoptsuite-4.0.1/lib/libscip.so: undefined symbol: history_length
```

My machine is Ubuntu 16.04 64 bits with SCIP Optimization 4.0.1 installed in /opt/scipoptsuite-4.0.1

I am using a virtualenv Python environment with Python 3.6 and the Python editor Pycharm.

I am really stuck.

[image]

I re-installed scipoptsuite with CMake Then make test within scipoptdir works fine. I also have the sub-directories lib and include as mentioned at [https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.rst] . I also run this command `make install INSTALLDIR=$SCIPOPTDIR SHARED=true` . Then I obtained the following error `(scip_env) dfg@dfg:~/thesis/programming/scip-pfd$ python3.6 atsp.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "atsp.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pyscipopt import Model, quicksum, multidict
  File "/home/dfg/thesis/programming/python_envs/scip_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyscipopt/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyscipopt.scip      import Model
ImportError: libscip.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
 Do I have to make some link or export a variable ? Thank You very much ! Regards

Comment: How did you install the SCIP library? Most likely it's trying to usethe wrong header files. Did you also work with an older SCIP version before?

Comment: Dear MattMillen, Thank You very much for your reply. I downloaded the the scipsuite-4.0.1 from http://scip.zib.de/#download. When installing scip I have done make install INSTALLDIR=$SCIPOPTDIR SHARED=true as recommended by pyscipopt. Do I have to reinstall my scip ? Actually in command line , > make test is working within the scipopt directory. Thank You very much

Comment: Huh, weird. And I suppose you also specified the SCIPOPTDIR during the setup.py execution? As a last resort, you might want to give CMake a try for installing SCIP.

Comment: I used pip install pyscipopt to install the Python interface. How can I do CMake a try to install SCIP ?

Comment: http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/CMAKE.php

Comment: I re-install with CMake scipoptsuite-4.0.1  Then make test within scipoptdir works fine. I also have the sub-directories lib and include as mentioned at https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.rst . I also run this command make install INSTALLDIR=$SCIPOPTDIR SHARED=true . Then I obtain the following error

Comment: can you verify that the directory `$SCIPOPTDIR` contains `lib` and `include` and that those also contain the relevant libs and headers?

Comment: I verified. Yes the directory `$SCIPOPTDIR` contains `lib` and `include` repositories, with relevant libs and headers. I have also added these line to `~\.bashrc` file : `export SCIP_HOME="/home/dfg/prog/scipoptsuite-4.0.1"
export PATH="${PATH}:${SCIP_HOME}/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${SCIP_HOME}/lib"` And after that. It comes back to the primaty error, which is `history_length`

Comment: I probably know what's the root of the problem: `history_length` belongs to readline. Try installing SCIP without readline, i.e. `make READLINE=false` for the Makefile or `cmake -DREADLINE=off´ for CMake. Python comes with it's own readline lib that is incompatible to the one that your system provides. The joy of library dependencies!

Comment: Thank you @mattmilten.  I run this command within the scipoptsuite repository `make install INSTALLDIR=$SCIPOPTDIR SHARED=true READLINE=false`. But now, the lib `libscip.so` is not found

Comment: Please use CMake. The lib generated by the pure Makefile might have another name that is not recognized by PySCIPOpt.

Comment: Please do you know how to share library when using `cmake`. Here is what I have done and obtain :

Comment: You need to run make afterwards in the build directory. PLEASE read the manual properly before asking questions.

Comment: Thank You @mattmillen, I have done what you advised. I have deleted my previous `scipsuiteopt` then re-install with `cmake` with `readline` off.

Comment: Thank You @mattmillen, I have done what you advised. I have deleted my previous `scipsuiteopt` then re-install with `cmake` and  `readline` off. That works fine in command line `(scip_env) dfg@dfg:~/thesis/programming/scip-pfd$ python atsp.py 

Miller-Tucker-Zemlin's model:
Optimal value: 330.0
x(1,4) = 1.0
x(2,3) = 1.0
x(3,5) = 1.0
x(4,2) = 1.0
x(5,1) = 1.0
u(5) = 4.0
u(2) = 2.0
`

Comment: However, I think one problem come from my editor `PyCharm` which doesn't recognize `Model` and `quicksum`

Comment: Maybe you need to activate the scip_env virtual environment? PySCIPOpt is probably not installed in your global PYTHONPATH

Comment: Moreover, I copied `libscip.so` located at `./scipoptsuite/build/lib/libscip.so` to `/usr/local/lib/libscip.so`. Then that also work with the editor PyCharm :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank You @mattmillen, I have done what you advised. I have deleted my previous scipsuiteopt then re-install with cmake and readline off. That works fine in command line `(scip_env) dfg@dfg:~/thesis/programming/scip-pfd$ python atsp.py Miller-Tucker-Zemlin's model: Optimal value: 330.0 x(1,4) = 1.0 x(2,3) = 1.0 x(3,5) = 1.0 x(4,2) = 1.0 x(5,1) = 1.0 u(5) = 4.0 u(2) = 2.0`

Moreover, I copied `libscip.so` located at `./scipoptsuite/build/lib/libscip.so`  to `/usr/local/lib/libscip.so`. Then that also works with the editor PyCharm :)